# Excel QueryTable is zeroing negative values

Tags: excel, vba

I am a very limited user of VBA.  In the past, I've copied code found here and managed to muddle through.  I've been using the following code every day for at least a year to import stock prices from Yahoo Finance.  It's worked flawlessly until this week.

It grabs a csv file from Yahoo where the first three columns are Stock symbol, market price and daily change.  For some reason this week, the third column has started to show only non-negative values.

Here's the code:

```
Dim URL As String: URL = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & Symbols & "&f=sl1c6gn0" & "&e=.csv"


Dim destCell As Range


Set destCell = Worksheets("Y Prices").Range("A" & qStart - 3)

With destCell.Parent.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & URL, Destination:=destCell)
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

destCell.Parent.QueryTables(1).Delete
```

As an example, with `URL = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=MON,ACI,ACM,ADSK,ADTN,ARLP,ATLS,AVGO,AWAY,BITA,BTU,CHL,CIE,CLC,CLF,CPN,CPSI,CSOD,CSX,CTL,DB,DMND,EXXI,EZCH,FIVE&f=sl1c1gn0&e=.csv"`

Pasting this link into a browser will produce a csv file with positive and negative numbers in the third column.  But when I run this code in VBA, the third column only contains the positive numbers.  All cells with negative numbers are left empty.

Any suggestions why this has started happening?

Comment: Actually when I run that query in yahoo, I get 4 columns, the last of which is all n/a

Comment: When I run that code with your made up URL I get negative values put in the sheet. Perhaps you have set the format of those cells to something that doesn't display negatives. Otherwise everything looks fine in your code and on the Yahoo side.

Comment: I get five columns, the last of which is N/A.  I don't use that column.  But you should see data in the third column that has both positive and negative numbers.  Running the code in VBA, the negative numbers are all missing.

Comment: Thanks JNevil for running the code.  I don't see any direct or conditional formatting tied to that worksheet at all, but it is good to know that it works for you.  I must have something causing this to format this way.

Comment: Closing and reopening the program seems to have corrected the error.  Duh!  Sorry.